# How do I make the Monero GUI client report a different amount?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

How do I make the Monero client say a different amount of XMR on the big orange rectangle on the top left, instead of the actual one? Of course this is just a cosmetic change. I am running on linux.

Comment: I also want to not show recent transactions. I'm thinking I could somehow make the client "pause" on an outdated block?

Comment: To be more specific, I want to hide my recent transactions from the GUI wallet.

Comment: Settings->Layout->Hide balance ??